# Matching Columns in a Data Frame and performing operation in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, logic

There are two data frames A and B. I have to Match `ID` Column of `Data Frame A` with the `Unique_ID` column of `Data Frame B`. If there are any  matches I am trying do the  operation Like if any of the  `Index` column of the matched `ID` in the `Data Frame A` is greater than the `Super_Index` of the `Data frame A` like `A.Index >B.Super_Index`. If there exists then loading the `ID` in the separate data frame. This is just a sample data from the big data set I have.

Data Frame A: 

`PROD Index  ID
A   1   11
B   2   22
B   5   33
C   6   44
B   6   22
B   1   66
B   4   11
B   3   11
A   8   33
B   1   44
G   5   11
M   6   11`

Data Frame B:

`New  Super_Index  Unique_ID
A   4   11
S   5   22
C   2   33
B   9   44`

OUPUT:

`ID
11
22
33`

Is there any way to do this? I am new to Python and have used R before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `merge_asof`

```
pd.merge_asof(dfA.sort_values('Index'),dfB.sort_values('Super_Index'),left_on='Index',right_on='Super_Index',left_by ='ID',right_by='Unique_ID',allow_exact_matches =False).dropna().Unique_ID.unique()
Out[346]: array([33., 11., 22.])
```